Wird 'entlang' bei Kontaktstellung immer zusammengeschrieben?
In meinem großen Wörterbuch stehen nur drei Verben, deren Infinitiv-Form mit 'entlang-' beginnt. Für andere einfache richtungsangebende Partikeln gibt es aber erheblich mehr Beispiele. Für 'vorbei' sind es 19 und für 'herum' und 'zurück' über hundert.
Macht es was aus, ob es sich um 'den Fluss entlang' oder 'am Fluss entlang' handelt?

Du hast leider nicht angegeben, welches Wörterbuch du konsultiert hast. Wiktionary kennt erheblich mehr Verben, die mit entlang- beginnen. Im Wiktionary-Eintrag über das Präfix entlang- werden diese 49 Verben aufgelistet:

entlangblicken, entlangbrausen, entlangbummeln, entlangeilen, entlangfahren, entlangfliegen, entlangfliehen, entlangflitzen, entlangführen, entlanggaloppieren, entlanggehen, entlanggleiten, entlanghangeln, entlanghasten, entlanghinken, entlanghumpeln, entlanghuschen, entlangklettern, entlangkommen, entlangkriechen, entlangkurven, entlangkutschieren, entlanglaufen, entlanglotsen, entlangmarschieren, entlangpaddeln, entlangpatroullieren, entlangpromenieren, entlangrasen, entlangrudern, entlangsausen, entlangschlängeln, entlangschleichen, entlangschlendern, entlangschreiten, entlangschwimmen, entlangsegeln, entlangspazieren, entlangstreichen, entlangstreifen, entlangstürmen, entlangtappen, entlangtapsen, entlangtorkeln, entlangtraben, entlangtuckern, entlangwandern, entlangziehen, entlangzuckeln

Für die meisten dieser Verben hat Wiktionary zwar keine eigenen Einträge, aber immerhin gibt es für 12 dieser Verben doch einen Eintrag.

Frage:
Macht es was aus, ob es sich um 'den Fluss entlang' oder 'am Fluss entlang' handelt?
Antwort:
Streng genommen ja. Verben, die mit entlang- beginnen, beschreiben keine Lage, sondern eine Bewegung. Die Präposition am (Zusammenziehung von an dem) beschreibt aber keine Bewegung, sondern eine Lage. Daher passt entlang- mit am eigentlich nicht zusammen. (Dasselbe gilt auch für das Paar entlang- + an der.) Aber in der Umgangssprache wird darauf nicht immer streng geachtet. Insbesondere ist die Präposition am kein Hindernis beim Verstehen von Sätzen, die ein Verb enthalten, das mit entlang- beginnt. Wenn man jedoch völlig korrektes Deutsch schreiben oder sprechen will, sollte man Verben, die mit entlang- beginnen, nur mit Präpositionen kombinieren, die eine Bewegung beschreiben.

Fragt sich aber, ob es sinnvoll ist, Verben als Infinitivform aufzulisten, denn dabei sieht es aus, als ob es im Deutschen an die zwanzigtausend Verben gäbe! Es gibt aber hoechstens zweitausend eigentliche Verben, die durch Partikeln und Präfixe fast beliebig zu erweitern sind.

@Georg: Es ist sehr sinnvoll, die vollständigen Verben aufzulisten, weil das ja eigenständige Wörter sind, die ganz eigene Bedeutungen haben. Vergleiche z.B.: Ich werde mit dem Auto fahren. Ich möchte Neuigkeiten erfahren. Mit dieser Chemikalie muss man besonders vorsichtig verfahren.

Die Ausführungen ab "Streng genommen" sind falsch, denn eine Bewegung kann sehr wohl durch einen Ort - an dem sie stattfindet - beschrieben werden. Man kann auch nicht nur "in die Stadt fahren" (Bewegung in Richtung auf die Stadt), sondern genausogut "in der Stadt fahren" (Bewegung innerhalb der Stadt, durch Angabe eines Ortes).

@bakunin Es lässt sich wohl retten, wenn man für "Bewegung" "Richtung" einsetzt.

Das "entlang" ist im Prinzip eine Bewegung. Sobald
man dies kartographisch benutzt, ist das abgehen/entlanggehen
implizit; dies konvertiert Entfernung zu Zeit, und damit
zu Bewegung. "Lang" ist eine Entfernungsangabe; bedeutet
dass man ungef"ahr per Massband eine Art Strecke
in einer Richtung bestimmen kann. Insbesondere bei Fl"ussen und
Gew"assern, auf Deichen oder bei Z"aunen/Strassen
ist dieser linienhafte Eindruck was "entlang" induziert.
Man sagt "er guckte die Strasse entlang", obwohl sich da
nichts bewegt sondern der zeitliche Eindruck nur durch Augenbewegung
entsteht.

Der Unterschied von "den Fluß ..." oder "am Fluß..." ist wohl minimal. "Am Fluß..." bedeutet wohl eine engere Anbindung, wie man sie
beim radeln oder zu-Fuß-gehen sozusagen in Sichtweite erfährt. Wenn ich jetzt an eine Autobahn oder Eisenbahn denke, die nur irgendwie geographisch locker in die gleiche Richtung führt, ist das "den" passender. Wenn zum Beispiel wasserliebende Gewächse genannt werden, heißt es wahrscheinlich "Am Fluß entlang stehen..."

Ich sehe den Unterschied genau umgekehrt. (Möglicherweise hängt es vom Kontext ab.) Mit dem Boot fahre ich "den Fluß entlang", da würde ich keinesfalls "am Fluß entlang" verwenden. "Am Fluß entlang" ist aus meiner Sicht nahe beim Fluß, aber nicht genau darauf oder darin.

Da sehe ich keine Diskrepanz. "Am" bedeutet N"ahe wie in "An der Ampel stehen",
"Am Brunnen vor dem Tore..", oder "der Kahn am Ufer". Wenn man aber so nahe ist,
dass keine Dinstanz mehr ubrigbleibt, ist es nicht mehr "am". So ist es
"ich stehe am Bordstein" aber "ich stehe auf dem Burgersteig". "Ich stehe am Haus"
aber "ich stehe auf/in der Einfahrt". Mit dem Boot "paddle ich am Ufer entlang",
insofern hier "auf dem Fluss" schon eine Entfernung zum Ufer bedeutet.

Ich beziehe mich auf die Beispiele entsprechend der Fage 'den Fluss entlang' oder 'am Fluss entlang' und die Aussage "Am Fluß..." bedeutet wohl eine engere Anbindung, und Wenn ... die Autobahn ... nur irgendwie geographisch locker in die gleiche Richtung führt, ist das "den" passender, nicht auf andere Beispiele mit "am" oder "auf" ohne "entlang". Die Antwort verstehe ich zusammengefaßt als "den Fluß entlang" würde auf einen größeren Abstand hindeuten als "am Fluß entlang". Das sehe ich genau umgekehrt.
